# DT-06 WIFI. How to program with Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi

I have a DT-06 wireless WiFi. I can connect using my phone but I cannot access 192.168.4.1/status.html or /wifi_set.html like in the tutorial

I put this module in wiring with Arduino Uno on 5v. I notice that the LED is low lighting until I put pin state in GND. Then I get full power red led. I put RX module to TX Arduino and TX module to RX Arduino but i can not access it using Arduino.

How can I program this module or how can I access? Any tutorial links are welcome.

Thanka. Sorry for my English.

L.E.

Module RX - Arduino TX
Module TX - Arduino RX
Module VCC - Arduino 5v
Module GND - Arduino GND
Module STATE - GND

My module has a red led on it. This led is low lighting until i put pin STATE in GND. After that the red led is full lighting.

After i put VCC and GND i can "see" my module using my phone wireless connection

Comment: I didn't really understand, what LED you mean exactly. Also provide a schematic or wiring diagram, so that we can see, how you connected the DT-06. It sounds, like as if you use a digital output pin to provide it with power. This would be absolutely wrong.

Comment: If you refere to a tutorial, please provide a URL to it.

Comment: Please check my edit in the question

Answer (score 1):

Are you wiring it to Arduino pins 0 & 1? These are hard-wired to the other processor on the Arduino board that handles USB to/from your PC. There may be interference with the DT-06 unless you disconnect from your PC after upload. But then you'll need an alternate source of power to the Arduino.

You can pick another pair of pins and use the SoftwareSerial library (up to 9600 baud) to talk to the DT-06. Make sure Arduino and the DT-06 use the same baud-rate. You may have to experiment to find what baud-rate the device has now, in order to set it to 9600.

Update:

> Do i have to use any resistence?

Two sites I looked at described the DT-06 voltage requirement as:
"Working voltage: 4.5V~6.0V, TTL working voltage: 3.3V (compatible with 5.0V);", so you should be OK without voltage divider resistors.

> And what settings to make in arduino IDE before uploading code?

You won't need to change your IDE to upload code to the Uno.

Comment: Can you please make me a wiring scheme and also tell me the arduino code?

Comment: [This discussion](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/38289/at-command-is-not-responding-on-serial-monitor) talks about using SoftwareSerial and setting the baud-rate. It was written about an ESP8266 module but most of it will apply to your module, too.

Comment: Do i have to use any resistence?

Comment: And what settings to make in arduino IDE before uploading code?