# AT firmware upgrade in ESP-01 using Arduino UNO R3

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, firmware

I need to upgrade the AT firmware in ESP-01 by using Arduino UNO R3 serial interface. Do I need to remove the Microcontroller Chip from the DIP socket before burning firmware? Does it going to affect Arduino Bootloader?

Comment: Take a look at my [answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/75499/40646) to another similar question.

Comment: Thank you it helped a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to remove the Microcontroller Chip from the DIP socket before burning firmware?

No, just connect RESET to GND to stop the MCU from running.

> Does it going to affect Arduino Bootloader?

No.