# ESP8266-01E is not responding after successful flash

Tags: esp8266, firmware

I have flashed an ESP8266 with the ESP8266 flash downloader that said my flashing had succeeded.

But when I sent an AT command from the serial monitor it didn't respond and the TX/RX LED from the ESP8266 didn't respond either. I checked all baudrates from 300-200000, but nothing.

I was using CH340 USB to TTL for flashing wired like this:

```
USB -> ESP8266
3,3v ->CH_PD and VCC
GND -> GND and GPI0 (only when flashing)
TX -> RX
RX -> TX
```

I was flashing to downgrade the firmware; the default firmware from shop was SDK 1.5.4, AT VERSION 1.1.0.0.

[image]

I have been frustrated with this, because this is my second module.

Comment: There are several files that need to upload the the ESP-01, it is unclean what you have done, what files to uploaded and where to upload also depend on the size of the flash memory you have for your ESP-01. Take a look at this =[link](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/75499/40646) to see if it will help.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

My module is esp8266-01S, i need to set the SPI MODE to DOUT, BAUDRATES=115200, SPI SPEED 40MHz and the software is NODEMCU FLASHER.

The important keyword is "DOUT".

I have been flash many times but with not DOUT SPI METHOD. I thought change it will not fix that. I was using QIO SPI MODE but it doesn't work.