# Esp8266-01 and Arduino

Tags: esp8266

I recently bought an ESP8266 (ESP-01s). When I first connected it to Arduino,AT commands showed. Then when I uploaded other code,the commands stopped showing. I flashed it using many flashing tools and firmwares and the flashing was successful but AT commands still not showing. ESP is not responding to any code I execute in Arduino.

Comment: *"Please help"* How exactly? You need to give something to work with. Code, wiring, etc.

Comment: When you put code on the esp you remove the AT code. If your way AT commands you have to put on the AT code

Comment: ESP-01 by default shipped with AT Command firmware, when you upload an Arduino sketch, it override the firmware and replaced with Arduino boot loader and sketch (i.e. ESP-01 became an Arduino). If you want to get back the AT Command firmware, see my answer [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/75499/40646) on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem with newcommers to the ESP8266. It ships with AT commands working and as soon as you try putting your own code on it the AT commands stop working.

Well, of course they do.

The AT commands aren't something the ESP8266 does. It's something the software installed on the ESP8266 does, and you just deleted that software and put your own software on.

You can *either* have AT commands (by installing the correct AT firmware for your board) *or* run your own software on it - not both (unless, of course, you write your software in such a way that it responds to AT commands, but that's a completely separate thing...)