# All AT commands return Fail

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I'm trying to send data from sensor to ThingSpeak, but the AT commands always return Fail. They work sometimes and send data.  But, most of the time they return fail.

My Connections:

| ESP | Arduino |
| --- | --- |
| Gnd | Gnd |
| Vcc, ChPD/En | 3.3v |
| Rx | 2 |
| Tx | 3 |

My code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#include "DHT.h"

#define DHTPIN 10
#define DHTTYPE DHT11

#define RX 2
#define TX 3

#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

#define SensorPin 0          // the pH meter Analog output is connected with the Arduino’s Analog

#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 8

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
float phValue;

String AP = "Mukadam";       // AP NAME
String PASS = "28oct1997"; // AP PASSWORD
String API = "ZIGGVWBPU0BJ9A0I";   // Write API KEY
String HOST = "api.thingspeak.com";
String PORT = "80";

String f1 = "field1";
String f2 = "field2";
String f3 = "field3";
String f4 = "field4";

int countTrueCommand;
int countTimeCommand; 

boolean found = false; 

int valSensor = 1;

SoftwareSerial esp8266(RX,TX); 

float Celcius=0;
float Fahrenheit=0;

float b;

int buf[10],temp;

unsigned long int avgValue;

void setup() 
{
  lcd.begin();
  lcd.backlight();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  dht.begin();
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);

  sensors.begin();

  lcd.print("WT:");

  esp8266.begin(115200);

  sendCommand("AT",3,"OK\r\n\r\n");
  sendCommand("AT+CWMODE=1",5,"OK");
  sendCommand("AT+CWJAP=\""+ AP +"\",\""+ PASS +"\"",20,"OK");
}

void loop() 
{
  sensors.requestTemperatures(); 
  Celcius=sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);
  Fahrenheit=sensors.toFahrenheit(Celcius);

  Serial.print("C:");
  Serial.print(Celcius);

  lcd.setCursor(3,0);

  lcd.print(Celcius);

  String getData = "GET /update?api_key="+ API +"&"+ f1 +"="+String(Celcius);

  sendCommand("AT+CIPMUX=1",5,"OK");
  sendCommand("AT+CIPSTART=0,\"TCP\",\""+ HOST +"\","+ PORT,15,"OK");
  sendCommand("AT+CIPSEND=0," +String(getData.length()+4),4,">");

  esp8266.println(getData);

  delay(1500);countTrueCommand++;

  sendCommand("AT+CIPCLOSE=0",5,"OK");

  
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)       //Get 10 sample value from the sensor for smooth the value
  { 
    buf[i]=analogRead(SensorPin);
    delay(100);
  }

  for(int i=0;i<9;i++)        //sort the analog from small to large
  {
    for(int j=i+1;j<10;j++)
    {
      if(buf[i]>buf[j])
      {
        temp=buf[i];
        buf[i]=buf[j];
        buf[j]=temp;
      }
    }
  }

  avgValue=0;

  for(int i=2;i<8;i++)                      //take the average value of 6 center sample
    avgValue+=buf[i];

  float phValue=(float)avgValue*5.0/1024/6; //convert the analog into millivolt
  phValue=3.5*phValue;                      //convert the millivolt into pH value

  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);       
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);

  lcd.setCursor(9,0);
  lcd.print("pH:");
  lcd.setCursor(12,0);
  lcd.print(phValue);


  getData = "GET /update?api_key="+ API +"&"+ f2 +"="+String(phValue);
  sendCommand("AT+CIPMUX=1",5,"OK");
  sendCommand("AT+CIPSTART=0,\"TCP\",\""+ HOST +"\","+ PORT,15,"OK");
  sendCommand("AT+CIPSEND=0," +String(getData.length()+4),4,">");

  esp8266.println(getData);delay(1500);countTrueCommand++;

  sendCommand("AT+CIPCLOSE=0",5,"OK");

  lcd.setCursor(12,0);
  lcd.print(phValue);

  float h = dht.readHumidity();

  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("H:");
  lcd.setCursor(2,1);
  lcd.print(h);
 
  float t = dht.readTemperature();

  lcd.setCursor(8,1);
  lcd.print("AT:");
  lcd.setCursor(11,1);
  lcd.print(t); 
  lcd.setCursor(12,0);
  lcd.print(phValue);
}


void sendCommand(String command, int maxTime, char readReplay[]) {
  Serial.print(countTrueCommand);
  Serial.print(". at command => ");
  Serial.print(command);
  Serial.print(" ");

  while(countTimeCommand < (maxTime*1))
  {
    esp8266.println(command);//at+cipsend

    if(esp8266.find(readReplay))//ok
    {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  
    countTimeCommand++;
  }
  
  if(found == true)
  {
    Serial.println("OYI");
    countTrueCommand++;
    countTimeCommand = 0;
  }
  
  if(found == false)
  {
    Serial.println("Fail");

    countTrueCommand = 0;
    countTimeCommand = 0;
  }
  
  found = false;
}
```

And here is serial monitor output:

Comment: `work sometimes` and `always fail` are contradictory statements ... you cannot have both .... how do the commands fail? .... what errors do you get? .... does any specific command work more often?

Comment: SoftwareSerial is unreliable at 115200 baud. use 9600 baud. you must change the baud rate in AT firmware too

Comment: @jsotola always fails as in it always give Fail & sometimes work means just 1 day or 2 it will send data

Comment: I'm fairly new to using esp8266 how to change firmware baudrate?

Comment: [This answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/38289/at-command-is-not-responding-on-serial-monitor/38323#38323) (mine) describes how to change the ESP's power-on baud rate.

Comment: write and run a sketch which sends `AT+UART_DEF=9600,8,1,0,0` at 115200 baud. you only need to run it once. the esp remembers the baud rate. or you can use this one https://github.com/jandrassy/WiFiEspAT/blob/master/examples/Tools/ChangeATBaudRate/ChangeATBaudRate.ino

Comment: @Juraj Can provide me with the change I have to make in my sketch. As I have mentioned I'm new to esp and am getting confused by the instruction and tutorials on the internet